# How to run multiple Delphi RAD Server applications on same IIS?

Tags: delphi, interbase, delphi-10.4.2

I have created a RAD Server application and hosted it on the IIS. For this I had also installed the interbase 2020 instance using the RAD Server Multi-Site License.

Now, I want to host one more RAD Server application on the same IIS. I installed another instance of interbase 2020 instance specifying another port number and another instance name. Gave the RAD Server Multi-Site License again, and installation was done successfully.

But when i start the second instance, it fails to start, and the log said "the same license key already used by another instance".

How can I run more than 1 rad server application on an IIS ? Should there be an interbase instance for each such rad server application ? Multi-Site license wont support this ?

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why would you need to create a second Interbase instance? Can't you create 2 databases in the same instance?

Comment: Yes, i tried this, but only 1 app seems to be working in that case. Which ever app is called initially it will continue to work, and the other app wont respond. for example, if I have app1 and app2 in IIS, and  assume IIS has just started. If i call a service in app1, then all subsequent calls to app1 will work and any calls to app2  wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I got this fixed. Though I had created a second IB database in the existing instance,
app1, app2 were created within the "Default Web Site" of IIS. i deleted those, and  Created app1, app2 under "Sites" by assigning different port numbers, and opened the ports in windows firewall settings. Now, I have access app1 and app2 by specifying the ip address and the particular port number assigned to them.

Comment: You can also set up Multi-Tenancy in RAD Server. You can have multiple RAD Server sites and multiple InterBase databases on one server--all using one RAD Server license.